# What is the fastest way of searching items serialized into yaml, which is stored in a PostgreSQL-Database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, performance

We need to parse YAML configurations which have been serialized into a PostgreSQL-Database, which is hosted on heroku.

The table with the data we need has about 2.5 Million rows at the moment but will likely grow in size pretty fast.

The YAML-Data itself contains just simple config data, with a few hashes and some small arrays.

We need to be able to retrieve the YAML data in the fastest way possible from within our Rails App, which will also be hosted on heroku. 
What would be the best way to retrieve the data?

Will it be sufficient to simply traverse the database and deserialize the YAML data on the fly? 
Or should we rather create a new table, where we store the deserialized config data?
Also, will PostgreSQL be fast enough for this kind of task, or should we look into another database? E.g. nosql?

Comment: What kind of "searches" do you need to perform? If they can be expressed as text matches or regular expressions against a YAML serialized string, that's better than decoding with a stored procedure, which is better than retrieving all and deserializing manually. Also: how many matches do you expect from one search? If they are really many, then having to quickly search and fetch but deserialize all the same 50% of records may be not so different from fetching and deserializing 100% of the records and filtering afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  First, PostgreSQL is a very fast relational database.  But while there's nothing wrong with storing YAML as text in a database, what you're really doing (I assume) is storing structured data (the YAML) in a single field.  If the data is structured regularly, that is mostly it contains the same fields and values, then it should be stored in the relational database as structured data.  If it's loosely structured data, then a key-value store mechanism (whether a NoSQL database of some sort, or for that matter, the file system) might indeed be worth considering.

If you're traversing the database and deserializing the entire set of records, all 2.5M and growing, then you're storing them in memory already, so a tool like `memcached` (one of the cache stores supported by Rails) might be a good solution.  PostgreSQL is probably just fine for storing the data, unless it's huge -- 2.5M records is not a big number these days, and doing a full table scan is probably most likely not going to be the limiting factor -- more likely its the CPU hit of deserializing the YAML to ruby hashes/arrays.

But do you really need all 2.5M+ records in memory at once?  Why not fetch them as you need them?  When you say "the fastest possible way" the answer depends on what needs to be fast.  If you're willing to wait a few seconds for your app to load, then manage the data on your own from there (presumably storing changes as they occur, dealing with locking, concurrency, etc.) then yeah, memory is the way to go.  If you really need 2500 of the most frequently used records in memory, then a standard lazy-load caching strategy will likely be much simple to manage.

I think you're asking a rather general architecture and design question in terms of its implementation.  I don't think I or anyone else can provide a definitive answer without a more complete description of why, what and what your constraints are.  Edit the question to provide more context and detail, and perhaps you'll be able to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer!
I know, that my question was most likely to unspecific - I will try to specifiy our constraints in an edit, asap.